# Hive Data Flow Issues

Tags: hive, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

I am using Hive on HDInsights/Azure Spark 2.2 Cluster, submitting my queries through Ambari, the data is stored in External tables on Azure Data Lake. Staging and Target tables are partitioned.

I've been working on loading data in Hive today. The flow of data goes from .gz file -> staging table -> target table. It's an incremental load, left join from target to landing to preserve old data and then union all with new data for the full set.

I've noticed some behaviors that seem odd to me, was hoping to gather more insight.

Observation 1: After running the script through, I notice the new data is not present in the staging or the target from the original table/gz file. I wouldn't expect that since there's a UNION ALL present.

Observation 2: I did one step, manually loading data into my staging table from the .gz file/table. I run a simple count(*) on it. It returns 39k, great. I try running a select * where val = XYZ, it returns records, great again. I put a count(*) on that expression, starts returning 0 records.

Apologies if my thoughts are jumbled but wanted to know if there's anybody out there who's experienced similar occurrences and how to overcome them. Let me know any clarifications needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have spaces in your key ? have you tried trim(val) ?

Observation 2 is really surprising : from the same where predicates, you have rows being returned with a select * but nothing with select(*) ?

Could you include SQL queries and some rows of data ?